# How does Firestore handle offline / online deletions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This question is purely conceptual and I am trying to get a better grasp of how offline capability works for Firestore. So I understand that writes do not immediately go through and that they must be confirmed by the server and so offline writes sit on the device until it goes back online. I also understand that Firestore uses the last write wins schema. My question is, say somebody online deletes a document that someone offline is writing to or using, etc. What happens then when that offline person goes back online? Is a new document created now since essentially the offline user would be writing to a document that doesn't exist once they go back online?

Comment: `Is a new document created now since essentially the offline user would be writing to a document that doesn't exist once they go back online?` - Yes. Your `add()` function will create the document. In order to prevent that, you'd have to check whether that document exists and when it was last changed.

Comment: Answer below. But not that depends on the actual code, so I'd in general recommend to write and share that code. And if you've done that, you might as well test it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the code you used for writing to the document. If that could would auto-create the document if it doesn't exist (i.e. if it's a `set` and not an `update`), then it will indeed recreate the document.

If this is not the behavior you want, you can control it (in whatever way you want) with security rules.